# GET POST Rest Service not getting initialized

Tags: jersey, initialization, jax-rs

Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>de.vogella.jersey.jaxb</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.endpoint</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/atom/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.example.endpoint.DataWriteOptimizerOnLoad</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

DataWriteOptimizerOnLoad

```
package com.example.endpoint;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import com.example.hibernate.DataWriteOptimizer;

public class DataWriteOptimizerOnLoad extends DataWriteOptimizer implements
        ServletContextListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        getInstance();
    }
}
```

This initialization happens, I checked in catalina.out.

But this class does not get picked up by catalina.out.

```
package com.example.endpoint;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;

import com.mcruiseon.atom.api.tunnel.Consolidation;
import com.mcruiseon.atom.commons.AtomCommons;

@Path("/Consolidation")
public class EndPointConsolidation {

    @GET
    @Path("searchUsers/{passNumber}/{userMobileNumber}")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public ConsolidationSearchForUsersResponse searchUsers(
            @PathParam("passNumber") String passNumber,
            @PathParam("userMobileNumber") String userMobileNumber) {

        return Consolidation.searchForUsers(passNumber, userMobileNumber);
    }   
}
```

Nothing comes up on catalina.out when I run

> http://ipaddress:port//atom/Consolidation/searchUsers/9876543210

from the browser.

Comment: you have double // after port in url?

Comment: i guess your url should be 
`http://ipaddress:port/atom/Consolidation/searchUsers/passnumber/9876543210`

Comment: what jersey version you are using ?

Comment: I am using pre 2.0 jersey, not 2.0

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jersey 2.0 and later then it does not recognize init-param with name `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages` (web.xml). Try to change it to `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` as described in [JerseyProperties](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#PROVIDER_PACKAGES)